# Repeat values in new column for each group in pandas df

Tags: pandas, group-by

My input is as below and i want to create a new column quarter that should be repeated for each group of "name" as shown in the expected output

```
number  name        date1       date 2
1750    AAR CORP    12/18/2015  5/31/2012
1750    AAR CORP    3/23/2016   5/31/2012
1750    AAR CORP    9/23/2016   5/31/2012
1750    AAR CORP    12/22/2016  5/31/2012
1800    ABBOTT LAB  5/8/2012    12/31/2011
1800    ABBOTT LAB  8/7/2012    12/31/2011
1800    ABBOTT LAB  11/7/2012   12/31/2011
1800    ABBOTT LAB  5/8/2013    12/31/2011
1800    ABBOTT LAB  8/6/2013    12/31/2011
```

expected output:

```
number  name        date1       date 2      quarter
1750    AAR CORP    12/18/2015  5/31/2012   QTR 1
1750    AAR CORP    3/23/2016   5/31/2012   QTR 2
1750    AAR CORP    9/23/2016   5/31/2012   QTR 3
1750    AAR CORP    12/22/2016  5/31/2012   QTR 1
1800    ABBOTT LAB  5/8/2012    12/31/2011  QTR 1
1800    ABBOTT LAB  8/7/2012    12/31/2011  QTR 2
1800    ABBOTT LAB  11/7/2012   12/31/2011  QTR 3
1800    ABBOTT LAB  5/8/2013    12/31/2011  QTR 1
1800    ABBOTT LAB  8/6/2013    12/31/2011  QTR 2
```

Quarter values will repeat in set of 3 till the point there are rows for that name.

I am stuck after the simple groupby in pandas and not sure how to proceed with each group.

Comment: How exactly do you do your groupyby? If you can do that you must be already very close to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `cumcount` on the groups, then for repeating `1,2,3,..` sequence, get the `modulo` of `3`, `add` `1`

```
In [125]: 'QTR ' + ((df.groupby('name').cumcount() % 3) + 1).astype(str)
Out[125]:
0    QTR 1
1    QTR 2
2    QTR 3
3    QTR 1
4    QTR 1
5    QTR 2
6    QTR 3
7    QTR 1
8    QTR 2
dtype: object
```

Or,

```
In [142]: 'QTR ' + df.groupby('name').cumcount().mod(3).add(1).astype(str)
Out[142]:
0    QTR 1
1    QTR 2
2    QTR 3
3    QTR 1
4    QTR 1
5    QTR 2
6    QTR 3
7    QTR 1
8    QTR 2
dtype: object
```

Details

```
In [131]: df['quarter'] = 'QTR ' + ((df.groupby('name').cumcount() % 3) + 1).astype(str)

In [132]: df
Out[132]:
   number        name       date1       date2 quarter
0    1750    AAR CORP  12/18/2015   5/31/2012   QTR 1
1    1750    AAR CORP   3/23/2016   5/31/2012   QTR 2
2    1750    AAR CORP   9/23/2016   5/31/2012   QTR 3
3    1750    AAR CORP  12/22/2016   5/31/2012   QTR 1
4    1800  ABBOTT LAB    5/8/2012  12/31/2011   QTR 1
5    1800  ABBOTT LAB    8/7/2012  12/31/2011   QTR 2
6    1800  ABBOTT LAB   11/7/2012  12/31/2011   QTR 3
7    1800  ABBOTT LAB    5/8/2013  12/31/2011   QTR 1
8    1800  ABBOTT LAB    8/6/2013  12/31/2011   QTR 2
```